# Xcode 6 NSLogs not being shown in console

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, logging, console

So I have an Xcode project in my iCloud Drive and I've been working on it primarily on my Macbook Pro. It works fine there, all logs in the console are fine, but in the same project on my iMac the logs don't appear.

In fact the output window is completely empty when running an app on my iMac.

I've worked on this Xcode project on my iMac in the past and everything has worked fine. Have no idea what happened and how to get them to appear again.

Tech Specs:
iMac with OSX 10.10 (public release) and Xcode 6.0.1 (public release)

Macbook Pro with OSX 10.10 (public release) and Xcode 6.0.1 (public release)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what was causing it... But it fixed itself magically.

Thanks everyone for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Make sure you activated the console window]

Make sure you activated the console window in XCode

Comment: It is... I really don't know what could be doing it. I just redownloaded and installed Xcode and it still doesn't make a difference.